# Codeigniter - form validation callback order

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Hopefully a simple one. I have the following form validation rules:

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('timeStart', 'Day Start Time', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_validtime');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('timeEnd', 'Day End Time', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_validtime|callback_validtimeorder');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('interval', 'Interval', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_natural|callback_valid_interval');
```

The problem I have is that `callback_valid_interval` requires that `$this->input->post('timeStart')` and `$this->input->post('timeEnd')` are set. Currently my  callback_valid_interval function errors if the user has not completed the timeStart or timeEnd.

Is there any way I can set a dependency between the rules i.e. dont run the `callback_valid_interval` if the other rules have not passed?

Alternatively I can put in a manual check for these fields but was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Best regards, Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Codeigniter rules are ran left to right, as soon as one fails, it stops checking and marks the field as 'not passed validation' and set the message as the first failed rule.

You have all 3 fields as required so at a minimum you will have to have something in all 3 fields.  Each field is checked independently, so no you cannot (with the built in form_validation Class) create logical checks that are more complex than each field having independent rules.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will add additional validation as required.

Regards, Ben.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, except for the `matches[]` rule, nothing in Codeigniter's form validation class allows you to do this...

Since `CI_Form_validation::set_rules` does not return anything, you cannot use it in your `if` clause. I suggest you simply check if your values are set.

They will not be validated when your third rule callback is run, so they could be anything : do some checking in `callback_valid_interval`.

Something like this :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('timeStart', 'Day Start Time', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_validtime');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('timeEnd', 'Day End Time', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_validtime|callback_validtimeorder');
if ($this->input->post('timeStart') && $this->input->post('timeEnd')){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('interval', 'Interval', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_natural|callback_valid_interval');
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I thought that was the case but good to get a second opinion. Regards, Ben.

Answer (score 0):

Using the if(true AND true) method does what you want but I want to make sure you know what it does. set_rules doesn't evaluate rules, only the run function does. What jfoucher's code does is get the post values and if they aren't both set then it will create another rule. But this doesn't check trim or any other rule (other than required). However that method does work.

The only alternative I can think of is to rewrite you callbacks, or make your own rule by extending the form_validation class. I did the extension for my applications and it gives me a more universal way of validation, but it requires you to dig into CodeIgniter's core.